# passing values into another java project via runtime.exec()

Tags: java, netbeans

Here is my code to invoke a java project from another java project

```
package pkgtry;
import java.io.*;

public class Try 
{
  private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception 
  {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    pro.waitFor();
    InputStream inputStream = pro.getInputStream();
    int b = -1;
    while ( (b =  inputStream.read()) != -1 ) 
    {
        System.out.write(b);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     int x=10;
     try 
     {
            runProcess("javac -d . C:\\Users\\owner\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\input\\src\\input\\Input.java");
            runProcess("java input.Input");
     }
     catch (Exception e) 
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

This code is working perfectly. What i want is to pass an variable say 'x' from Try.java to Input.java

i would like to know the what all changes are to be made in Try.java to send the parameter and in Input.java to receive the parameter. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is Input.java located (In what package??)

Answer (score 1):

You need to append it to `command` and in `Input.java` in main method you will have this value stored in `args` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you want to pass to the called program is added to its commandline, like this

```
runProcess("java input.Input All Parameters You Want To Pass");
```

In Input.java you can retrieve these parameters by reading out `String[] args`, like this:

```
public class Input {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

will produce

```
All
Parameters  
You  
Want  
To  
Pass
```

But you should know that this is a rather heavy-handed way to make one piece of Java code call some other piece of Java code, you can add the jar produced by the project containing Input to the Try project and instantiate the Input class directly.  Calling via the command line is slow and cumbersome, and severely limits the communication between the two classes (command line parameters in one direction, an integer return value in the other direction.